# How do I prove point-wise convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+x/n^3)$ where $-1 < x < 1$ ? and uniform convergence on $[0;K]$ where $0<K<1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do I prove point-wise convergence for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log(1+x/n^3)$ where $-1 < x < 1$ ? and uniform convergence on interval $[0;K]$ where $0<K<1$.

I've tried to use Weierstrass, but without luck. Also, I cannot find an argument why the series converges for a point $-1<x<1$.

Comment: Just a hint: $log(a)+log(b)+log(c) = log(abc)$.

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in(-1,1)$ we have
$$\log\left(1+\frac x{n^3}\right)\sim_\infty \frac x{n^3}$$
so the given series is convergent by comparison with a convergent Riemann series.

For the uniform convergence we have for all $x\in[0,K]$
$$\left|\log\left(1+\frac x{n^3}\right)\right|\le \log\left(1+\frac K{n^3}\right)\sim_\infty \frac K{n^3}$$
hence we have the uniform convergence using the Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: How can you just state $$\log(1+x/n^3) \sim_{\infty} x/n^3$$ ? And what exactly does it mean :-) ?

Comment: Just use the Taylor series 
$$\log(1+x)\sim_0 x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\cdots$$